# Windows Authentication WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS, that must use https.

I am wanting to use the current user making a call to the service to be used to authenticate. I have setup my bindings like this on the service:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SOAPBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>

 <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AgentX.Services.Contracts.ICoreService" bindingConfiguration="SOAPBinding" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AgentX.Services.Contracts.ICoreService" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBinding_Service" />  
        
      </service>
```

The client is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICoreService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ICoreService" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />  
          </security>  
        </binding>
        
      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SOAPBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings> 
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://Services/Core.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SOAPBinding"
        contract="CoreServices.ICoreService" name="SOAPBinding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Do I have to implement code to perform what I looking for?

This is my code to make a call to the service:

```
using (var client = new CoreServiceClient())
            {
                var response = client.RetrieveData(request);
}
```

When I call the service from another machine I am getting an http error 500

Answer (score 0):

We need to add additional endpoints and behavior to make https work:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="AgentX.Services.Contracts.ICoreService">
     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AgentX.Services.Contracts.ICoreService" 
bindingConfiguration="SOAPBinding" />
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AgentX.Services.Contracts.ICoreService" bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBinding_Service" /> 
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICoreService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mybehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webbev">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

In addition, you could take a look at this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl) to see if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Would this be to the service or to the client?

Comment: It needs to be on the server-side.